# POST / PUT route constrainst issue on Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, routes

I came across this issue by accident. I have this route

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                  name: "RecycleCenters",
                  routeTemplate: "api/cars/{id}",
                  defaults: new { controller = "rc", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

and I have a controller like this

```
public class CarsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Car> Get() { ... }
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)  { ... }
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Car car)  { ... }
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, Car car)  { ... }
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)  { ... }
}
```

Basically what's happening is that my routing is allowing to make a POST request to an endpoint like this **/api/cars/id**, when it shouldn't because to create a new car the request should be to this endpoint **/api/cars**

I've found an answer for my issue in [this link](http://brockallen.com/2012/07/12/beware-the-default-webapi-route-with-post-requests-and-a-route-parameter/) but I want to know if the newer version of Web API has something already built in to prevent this scenario, if so then how to use it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use attribute routing you avoid this problem completely.  Instead of defining your routes with `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute` you use `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` and then place attributes on your controller methods:

```
public class CarsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/cars")]
    public IEnumerable<Car> Get() { ... }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/cars/{id}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)  { ... }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/cars")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(Car car)  { ... }

    [HttpPut]
    [Route("api/cars/{id}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, Car car)  { ... }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("api/cars/{id}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)  { ... }
}
```

You can also add a `RoutePrefix` attribute at the controller level to avoid duplicating some of the information in the route on each controller.  You can also avoid placing the Http verb attributes if you name your methods as you did, with the method name as the verb, but I prefer to use the attribute for each method for consistency.

[This](http://www.exceptionnotfound.net/attribute-routing-vs-convention-routing/) is a good article that talks about attribute routing versus convention routing.  It talks specifically about MVC, but it applies to web api as well.

Hope that helps.